# How find the value of this integral

Tags: calculus, integration

How can I compute $$\int_{-\pi}^\pi\frac{\sin(13x)}{\sin x}\cdot\frac1{1+2^x}\mathrm dx?$$

Answer (score 8):

**Hint 1:**
$$
\int\limits_{-a}^a f(x)dx=\int\limits_{-a}^a \frac{f(x)+f(-x)}{2}dx
$$
**Hint 2:**
$$
\frac{\sin (n x)}{\sin x}=
\frac{(e^{ix})^n-(e^{-ix})^{n}}{e^{ix}-e^{-ix}}=
\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} (e^{ix})^{n-k-1}(e^{-ix})^k
$$
**Hint 3:**
$$
\int\limits_{-\pi}^{\pi} e^{ikx}dx=
\begin{cases}
2\pi&\text{ if }\quad k=0\\
0  &\text{ if }\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}
\end{cases}
$$

Comment: @did Thanks!${}{}$

Comment: Sorry for the complexity in my previous comment. The sum in Hint 2 should be $$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}e^{i(n-2k-1)x}$$

Comment: I was going to suggest the change you just made to Hint 1  :-)

Comment: @robjohn, thanks for your attention. You are always on the alert :)

Comment: You're quite welcome! (BTW Hint 2 has become even more hinky; see my revised comment above).

Comment: I think it is clear and follows from $$a^n-b^n=(a-b)\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1}a^{n-1-k}b^{k}$$

Comment: But you still have $e^{ikx}$ instead of $e^{ix}$ inside the first pair of parentheses.

Comment: I fixed it; I hope you don't mind. (+1)

Comment: @robjohn Thanks!